# Java jmxremote not opening port

Tags: java, jmx

I've made a hello world java program to test how jmxremote works:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Press  to continue...");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

compiled it with `javac Main.java`, and run it like

`java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
     Main`

However the port never gets opened:

```
# telnet localhost 9010
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
```

(nc -l and netstat show same results). Java version is

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

and OS is Centos 6.5 (java installed from default repo with yum).

How do I fix this?

I've tried messing up the option names, but never got any info about an error - is jmx even available in java 1.5?

Comment: Does `netstat -p` show *any* ports opened for your process?

Comment: I was about to say "sorry, can't help you, works for me on 1.5 with Linux" (I still have a 1.5 install), but then I saw this in your post: `gij (GNU libgcj)`. It's entirely possible that `gcj` *doesn't* support JMX. Are you sure that's the Java install that you want to use?

Comment: @kdgregory, apparently not - what should I use instead?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CentOS, but the first thing I'd do is make sure that OpenJDK is installed, then make sure the links in `/etc/alternatives` point to it. Alternatively, you could download a Linux JDK from Oracle. One caveat: OpenJDK will be *at least* 1.6, and the earliest available Oracle JDK will be 1.7 (1.8 was just released, so you might want to wait on it). If you need 1.5 (you shouldn't), that will be a problem.

Comment: @kdgregory, thanks, I've removed java with yum and installed `java-1.6.0-openjdk`, now it seems to work!

Comment: Cool. I'm going to flag this question for a move to SuperUser, as it isn't really relevant to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like peoples say, libgcj is not a very good idea. It was a poor try from GNU peoples to fork a GPL licensed JVM that will compile java code to machine code, not byte code. It's now a dead project that never supported JMX.

A yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel will provide what you need.